# Check XML stored in Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

i have inherited some code where 66 rows of data are stored in a XML variable
how can i view this data? Tried select * from @variablename and get an error..sorry but new to this XML stuff

```
DECLARE @XMLVARIABLE XML
SET @XMLVARIABLE = (SOME SELECT QUERY) FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

Need to view @XMLVARIABLE to check everything has been passed in

using MSSQL 2014

thanks

Comment: This is not very clear. What defines "everything"?

Comment: XML support is **highly** vendor-specific - so which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Posting sample XML would be helpful but try something like this (assumes the variable @XMLVARIABLE actually contains your XML);

```
select
    someNode=Left(T.item.query('YourNodeName').value('.', 'varchar(255)'),255) 
from    
    @XMLVARIABLE.nodes('Node1/MoreNodesThatYouKnowAbout')AS T(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `SELECT .... FOR XML AUTO | RAW | PATH` to retrieve XML from tabular data. But in your case it seems, that the data you want to read, is an XML already.

What makes me wonder: you write about a `@XMLVARIABLE`. Is this code within a *stored procedure*, or is the XML living in a column of a table? If this is a column: What is the column's data type?

In any case you can see the content simply by writing

```
SELECT @XMLVARIABLE
```

or

```
SELECT AnXmlColumn FROM SomeTable
```

It is a differnt issue, to get data from **within** your XML. You will find a lot of examples around. Without a (reduced!) sample of your XML you won't get specific help...